# hook_user_insert not called when creating user in admin

Tags: drupal-7

`hook_user_insert` (Drupal 7) is not called when adding a user via the admin backend. I need to hook into this action to create a blank user profile (`profile2` module) for the user. I'm not sure if this is the intention or if it's a bug. It is called when a user registers via the frontend, but not when an admin user adds one via the backend.

If this is by design, is there an alternative hook I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

My bad. I didn't realise the hook was defined in my theme's `template.php` file. I moved it to a module and it works.

Comment: just for clarification: you had a seperate admin theme and because of that, it wasn't called?

Comment: I am using [Rubik](https://www.drupal.org/project/rubik) for admin theme and a custom theme for frontend. The hook was actually defined in the frontend theme.

Comment: These kind of hooks are implemented in module layer and have nothing with theme layer. So if you have enabled module with your hook implementation it should work independently to your themes and active theme.